# endpoint is exposes but trying to use netstat from another pod in the same namespace fails to reach it

Tags: kubernetes

Any help will be appreciated.

I'm trying to send a request from pod to pod inside a k8s cluster in the same namespace running on AWS.

I've added a pod that serves requests coming from port 5000,
from within the pod I manage to run a curl command successfully:

```
curl -i \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]' \
  localhost:5000/predict
```

I've added a service to the pod to expose an endpoint so I can send traffic to it:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: sklearn-iris-bentoml-deployment-sklearn-iris-example
  namespace: bentoml
  ownerReferences:
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/bentoml/services/sklearn-iris-bentoml-deployment-sklearn-iris-example
  labels:
    run: my-bentoml
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    run: my-bentoml
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The service:

```
➜ kubectl get svc -n bentoml
NAME                                                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
sklearn-iris-bentoml-deployment-sklearn-iris-example   ClusterIP   10.110.5.245   <none>        5000/TCP   5h6m
```

The endpoint:

```
➜ k get endpoints sklearn-iris-bentoml-deployment-sklearn-iris-example -n bentoml
NAME                                                   ENDPOINTS             AGE
sklearn-iris-bentoml-deployment-sklearn-iris-example   10.110.115.108:5000   5h6m
```

When I try to connect through telnet from a different pod in the same namespace, it fails:

```
root@my-shell:/# telnet 10.110.115.108 5000
Trying 10.110.115.108...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure whether I should configure a DNS since I don't have intentions to send traffic from outside the cluster so the network is mainly focused inside the cluster

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the the application pod is listening on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. This can typically be changed in the code of the application and depends on the language of the application.

Comment: what do you mean by application? the pod or the application which runs inside the container.

Comment: the application which runs inside the container. in the application code you must be starting a listener..depending on the language you need to configure it to listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: This is the netstat -an output:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: You are right! that was the problem,
I've started a service inside the pod, instead of running a container.
Now once I exposed the port from the docker file it is exposed to 0.0.0.0

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> This is the netstat -an output: tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5000 0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN – torpido 3 hours ago

It confirms the correctness of @Arghya Sadhu suspicions that your issue is related with the fact that **your application is configured to listen only on `localhost` address** which means **it can be reached only locally**. It would be seen more clearly if you pasted your `netstat` output with the headlines describing the content of each column.

Just take a look at an example. To illustrate the idea I deployed a set of **nginx** `Pods` from [the example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) available in the official k8s docs.

After listing the available pods and attaching to one of them via `kubectl exec` I ran `netstat -ntlp` command:

```
root@nginx-deployment-pod1:/# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/nginx: master pro
```

As you can see, the output in the third column is quite different than in your example. `0 0.0.0.0:80` means that the nginx server listens on all IPv4 addresses, assigned to all network interfaces in this system (in this case `container` or `Pod`). You can list all the available network interfaces and addresses with `ip a` or `ifconfig` commands.

Take a look at your command:

```
curl -i \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '[[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]' \
  localhost:5000/predict
```

You specified that you want to reach your app on port 5000 on `localhost`, but the fact it is available on `localhost` doesn't mean it will be reachable also outside the `Pod`. Let's take a look again at your `netstat` output (this time with headers):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp   0      0      127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

As you can see, your app listens or in other words binds only to `localhost` address (127.0.0.1). As @Arghya Sadhu mentioned, it is typically configured somewhere in the application code or in the configuration files if such are provided.

Keep in mind that you can expose some port further via `Services` and `Endpoints` but they must be first exposed by the `Pod`, which means the application which is running withing the `Pod` must be configured to listen on all local IP addresses.

Going back to our **nginx** example, it listens on `0.0.0.0:80` because it is configured to do so. It is done by the following directive present in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` configuration file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
...
```

or more specifically this line:

```
listen       80;
```

It equels to:

```
listen       0.0.0.0:80;
```

It basically means *"listen on all IP addresses / all network interfaces on port 80"*. If we changed it to:

```
listen       localhost:80;
```

or

```
listen       127.0.0.1:80;
```

**nginx** will be listening only on loclhost (127.0.0.1) address and it will be reachable only locally i.e. from within the `Pod`.

Every application does this in it's own way. If you deploy on kubernetes some custom application, which doesn't come with configuration files that enable you to defind listen or bind IP address, chances are it is hardcoded in the application code, so you need to find the fragment which is responsible for it. Look specifically for entries containing either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` and change it to `0.0.0.0` which means all IP addresses, searching for lines containing `listen` or `bind` keywords may be also helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer
The problem was that I started the service inside the pod instead of running a container using docker file with expose on the port